# ¿En qué formatos debo insertar un video en HTML para lograr la mejor cobertura de navegadores?

Tags: html, html5

Necesito insertar un video en un sitio web, pero el cliente me pide que lo hospede en el sitio (así que no puedo usar YouTube).

Al mismo tiempo, me pide que soporte la mayor cantidad de navegadores posible.

¿Qué formatos (sources) debería ofrecer para lograr la mejor cobertura de navegadores?

Comment: MP4 pero esta pregunta solicita opiniones o sugerencias. Una simple búsqueda en Google sería suficiente: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HRFVHIkk284J:https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Formatos_admitidos_de_audio_y_video_en_html5+&cd=3&hl=es-419&ct=clnk&gl=mx&client=safari

Comment: Agradezco tu sugerencia. El link que mencionás (que ya conocía) indica que MP4 no es suficiente para lograr la mejor cobertura, ya que Opera no lo soporta, y además no da ningún tipo de información sobre soporte mobile. Desgraciadamente esta no es la clase de dudas que se resuelven con el primer link de Google. Esto no es una cuestión de opinión; es cuestión de enumerar los 2-4 códecs de audio y video que sean compatibles con lo que hay en el mercado de browsers.

Comment: Revisa las analíticas de tu sitio y verifica si los usuarios de Opera son representativos, entonces sin estadísticas sobre tus visitas agrupadas por navegador, tu pregunta es muy amplia. Ademas de los 4 navegadores mencionados, 3 lo soportan... eso es la mayoría.

Comment: Desafortunadamente el sitio aún no existe, ya que me encuentro en proceso de desarrollarlo. Al mismo tiempo, saber qué códec es soportado por "la mayoría" de los navegadores no me acerca en nada a resolver mi duda, ya que, como sabrás, pueden configurarse varios sources para un mismo video, y el navegador elige cuál es el que más le conviene. Lo que estoy buscando es una combinación de sources que me ofrezca una cobertura razonablemente amplia. Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda, pero no creo que lo que estoy preguntando sea tan misterioso o vago como para ameritar esta discusión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, dejaría el formato `.mp4`, ya que tiene casi soporte en cualquier navegador, aun así, podrías añadir varios formatos de video a la etiqueta `video`.

> Referencia de soporte en navegadores `mp4` `webm` `ogg`:

- [mp4](http://caniuse.com/#search=mp4)
- [webm](http://caniuse.com/#search=webm)
- [ogg](http://caniuse.com/#search=ogg)

*Un posible ejemplo:*

```
<video controls preload>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg" /> 
    Su navegador no soporta la etiqueta de vídeo.   
</video>
```

Aquí te dejo otro ejemplo de [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp).